# javascript click function causes Content Security Policy error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

One of my chrome extension content scripts is executing a click function on an element like this

> var currencySelectorLink = document.getElementById('switcher-info');
> currencySelectorLink.click();

However the last line is causing the following error:

Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

I've spend multiple hours now trying to figure this out, maybe some of you will have an idea how to fix it. I absolutely have to trigger this click event, there is no way around it

EDIT:
After some more investigation I found out that it happens, because the link has href attribute with inline javascript:

```
<a class="switcher-info notranslate" href="javascript:void(0)" id="switcher-info"></a>
```

anybody has any ideas how to bypass that? If I do this:

```
currencySelectorLink.href= '#' ;
```

then error is gone, but it breaks website functionality and not exactly expected behavior comes out of this click event

Comment: Run the same in a devtools console and if you see the error, most likely it's unrelated to your extension. Otherwise I don't think this question can be answered without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) where `V` means verifiable i.e. the question should contain all info needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that the `<a href="javascript:void(0)"` code does is to prevent following on the link. You can do the same more pretty way:

```
currencySelectorLink.href= '#' ;
currencySelectorLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();  // Prevent default action (a following a link)
  }, false);
```

Note. Since you call `click()` you already have some event handler. You can insert `event.preventDefault();` into it instead of add a second handler. And use:

`<a class="switcher-info notranslate" href="#" id="switcher-info"></a>`

without `javascript:void(0)`.